# get checkbox attribute using javascript (array)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, checkbox

Hello guys i want to get the attribute of my checkbox. The checkbox was an array so i want to get the attribute of the checked checkboxes and put it on the textbox anf separate it with comma.

Here's my php/html

```
$query = $db->select('owners_information',array('*'),$con);

foreach($query as $q){
     //echo $q['lastname'];        
      $output .= '
      <tr>
        <td>'.$q["firstname"].'</td>
        <td>'.$q["middlename"].'</td>
        <td>'.$q["lastname"].'</td>
        <td>'.$q["land_area"].'</td>
        <td><input type="text" value="'.$q["OCPC_ID"].'" name="ocid[]">
        <input type="checkbox" value="'.$q["land_area"].'" name="checkval[]" attr="'.$q["OCPC_ID"].'"></td>
      </tr>
      ';

  }
if($query > 0){
    echo '<input type="text" name="textval" id="textval">';
    echo '<br><input type="text" name="ocpc_id" id="ocpc_id">';
    echo '<input type="button" name="merge" id="merge" value="Merge" onclick="mergeFunc()">';
    echo '<input type="button" name="addNew" id="addNew" value="Add New RPU" onclick="addMerge()" style="display:none;">';
    echo $output;
  }else{
    echo "No data found";
  }
```

And here's my javascript

```
function mergeFunc() {

var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('checkval[]');
var cd = document.getElementsByName("checkval[]");

var val_id = "";
for (var l=0, n=cd.length;l<n;l++) 
{
  if (cd[l].checked) 
  {
    val_id += ","+cd[l].attr;
  }
}
if (val_id) val_id = val_id.substring(1);

alert(val_id);


var vals = "";
for (var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) 
{
  if (checkboxes[i].checked) 
  {
      vals += ","+checkboxes[i].value;
  }
}
if (vals) vals = vals.substring(1);


$('#ocpc_id').val(val_id);
$('#textval').val(vals);
$('#merge').hide();
$('#addNew').show();
}
```

i want to get the attribute of the checkbox named `checkval[]`. I want to get what's inside the `attr` array. I hope you could help me guys.

Comment: what attr are you trying to get from the checkbox?

Comment: sorry sir i've updated my code then i want to get the `attr="'.$q["OCPC_ID"].'"` sir in my checkbox

Comment: you mean the value of the input text?

Comment: post the markup you have created with php

Comment: no sir the `attr` of my checkbox. i want to get the `attr` of my checkbox named `checkval[]`

Comment: ok post your html

Comment: my html sir is inside my `php` just look above sir

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152481/discussion-between-prasanna-venkatesh-and-angel1108).

Comment: I am asking for a pure html without php

Comment: `<input type="checkbox" value="'.$q["land_area"].'" name="checkval[]" data-ids="'.$q["OCPC_ID"].'" id="checkval[]">`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click',function(){
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('checkval[]');
  var input = document.getElementsByName('ocid[]');
  var checkval = '';
  var checkid = '';
  for(var i=0;i<checkboxes.length;i++) {
    if(checkboxes[i].checked){
      i==0 ? checkval += checkboxes[i].value : checkval += ","+checkboxes[i].value;
      i==0 ? checkid += input[i].value : checkid += ","+input[i].value;
    }
  }
  console.log(checkval+" "+checkid);
});
```

See the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/s0v6z1g6/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var val_id = "";
for (var l=0, n=cd.length;l<n;l++) 
{
  if (cd[l].checked) 
  {
    val_id += ","+cd[l].getAttribute("attr");
  }
}
if (val_id) val_id = val_id.substring(1);
```

I've change `val_id += ","+cd[l].attr;` to `val_id += ","+cd[l].getAttribute("attr");`

Thanks for your time guys.